# Creating an API with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I am just wondering what is the best approach in creating a RESTFUL API in Rails? Should I use Rails-API or Grape gem? What are the benefits/disadvantages of each? Is there a better alternative approach?

Comment: This might be a little too subjective. Can you define "best"? Can you describe your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The good news is you can create REST APIs in Rails easily without either gem. There's a lot that goes into REST, so I don't think I can completely answer your question here. Fortunately, if you following Rails' conventions, you probably already have a REST API.

It looks like both of those gems are intended for cases where you are not using Rails.  Rails-API says "The main example for its usage is in API applications only, where you usually don't need the entire Rails middleware stack nor template generation." Grape is designed for Rack applications, which offer a tiny bit of what Rails has to offer.

I would suggest taking a look at the book "Restful Web Services" by Richardson, Ruby, and Hansson. He does a good job of explaining REST and its advantages. The examples are in Rails, so it'll give you a great start to answering your question. I really enjoyed it and found it helpful in creating REST services in Rails.